# check image dimensions before upload django

Tags: ajax, django, image, upload

I made ajax image upload. How can I get image dimensions before file is uploaded? Or how can I stop uploading.

I wrote custom upload handler and have strange situation. If I'am trying to stop uploading file in "new_file" procedure by raising StopUpload(True) error - it works, but if I'am trying in receive_data_chunk procedure - it does not (actually django stops processing file, but server is still receiving data from client).
I use apache+mod_python.

Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rolling your own, I would use something like [django-jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload)

Comment: Tnx. This is a nice plugin. But it can't stop a file upload process. And I still have a question. How can I stop a file upload process? How can I get image dimensions from the request header?

Comment: I've always done it server side, post loading, unless the file is huge.  If the file is huge it's probably a DOS and can just be shutdown.  Client side requires something like Flash.

Comment: Shudder.  Me neither, that's why I just do it server side :-P